# AskDifferent and AndroidEnthusiast profile pages

Tags: discussion, user-interface, profile-page, design

Why is it that on [AskDifferent](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/43377/troniczomb) and [AndroidEnthusiasts](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/28670/troniczomb) the profile tab sections are left aligned while on every other SE site, or at least all the ones that I have signed into at some point in time, are right aligned? Is there a reason for this?

[image]

Comment: Looks like a bug to me. The columns aren't even aligned with the info displayed below. They both appear on the right (like on any other SE sites) on the mobile version.